# How to use data validation to force google sheets column into phone number formatting

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column where phone numbers should be entered.  I want to use data validation in GOOGLE SHEETS to not allow any input that isn't in standard phone number format {{ example: (302) 242-0772 }}

I have this rule currently in my sheet, but it's basically giving an issue for anything input (even when something is in phone number format).

I also have it set to the correct range (all of column F, starting with F3)

=AND(ISTEXT(F3), REGEXMATCH(F3, "^(\d{3}) \d{3}-\d{4}$"))

I realize that the rule works when I actually type in the parantheses/hyphen.  However, because they are being set with google sheets formatting and only a 10 digit number is shown in the formula bar, the data validation doesn't work.

I originally tried to just limit the column to 10 digit numbers, but that wasn't working either (denying every entry).  This was my rule for that logic:

=AND(ISNUMBER(F3), LEN(F3) = 10)

Any idea how I can solve this issue? Ultimately, I have a 10 digit number that is being formatted as a phone number - I want to lock it so no user can input anything other than 10 digits.

Comment: But won't a number formatted 3, 3, 4 actually have a length of 12? so len() needs to check for 12? Also, isnumber() should fail with 2 spaces included...

Comment: so the format is only in that sense because of the google sheets formatting rule. in the formula bar, even when formatted as a phone number, the formula bar simply shows 10 digits (no other characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stated your requirement for 10 digit numbers.

In Google Sheets, you can limit the user to input 10 digits, and also be able to format as a number by doing the following:

Set Data validation criteria for the range as "**Is between**".

Input the lowest number `1000000000` and the highest number `9999999999`

Then set **Advanced options** to "**Reject the input**"

Then click "**Done**"

[image]

Once done, go to **Format > Number > Custom number format**

Use this format:

`(000)000-0000`

Then click "**Apply**"

Now the 10 digit number will be accepted, but other lengths will be rejected, and the number will be formatted as a phone number.

*Note: this will reject numbers where leading digits in the 10 digit string are zeros.*